# Matrix $A$ is not invariant to the permutation of $x$, in terms of $Ax=y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We can view
$$Ax=y$$
as a linear mapping from elements in set $x$ to that in set $y$.

In some cases, $A$ refers to a static phenomenon (say, a physical law). But, changing the order of elements in x, the row and column need to be permuted accordingly to represent the same law. This is annoying (multiple matrices exist for the exact same law).

question: is there a way to order the row and column of such a matrix to make a 'standard' version? or should we choose another formulism instead of matrix equation for invariance purposes?

Comment: The matrix that represents a linear transformation depends on the choice of basis. You can choose one so the matrix representation is diagonal or Jordan (assuming $A$ is square).

Comment: Why use $x$ for both a vector and a set?